# MySQL trigger cannot use the same table in UPDATE statement

Tags: mysql, triggers

So basically I have tried to create a trigger that updates a score in my 300challenge table by adding scores for pushups, pullups and a 3mile run. The score for the 3mile run is in the big `SELECT` below.

```
create trigger update_wscore
AFTER INSERT
ON 300challenge FOR EACH ROW

Create table temp(3mile_score integer);
insert into temp(3mile_score) 
select 
  case 
    WHEN TIMEDIFF (3mile , '00:18:00') > '00:00:10' 
      THEN
         CASE 
            WHEN
              100 - (EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM TIMEDIFF (3mile, '00:18:00')) * 6 +
              FLOOR(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM TIMEDIFF (3mile, '00:18:00')) / 10)) < 0
            THEN 0
         ELSE 
              100 - (EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM TIMEDIFF (3mile, '00:18:00')) * 6 +
              FLOOR(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM TIMEDIFF (3mile, '00:18:00')) / 10))
         END
  ELSE 100
END
FROM 300challenge
WHERE wscore IS NULL;

UPDATE 300challenge
SET wscore = pushups * 2 + pullups * 5 + (select * from temp);

drop table temp;
```

I've tried using the `SELECT` directly in the `UPDATE wscore` statement replacing the `select * fom temp` but it didn't work saying that I can't use `300challenge` table in the `SELECT FROM` clause inside the `UPDATE` statement.

After that I tried what is currently displayed above, creating a temporary table in which I dump the score and them read it in order to be used in the `UPDATE`.

But apparently this method isn't good enough to trick the system as it now throws an error that says `Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger.`

I have kind of ran out of ideas, so if anyone could give some suggestions they would be very welcomed.

**UPDATE:**

I have also tried now removing the `CREATE TABLE TEMP` from the trigger, created the table outside the trigger (once) and replaced the last line of the trigger, `drop table temp` with a `truncate table temp`, but apparently my webhost doesn't allow triggers as 
`TRIGGER command denied to user '--'@'localhost' for table '300challenge'`

My code is now this

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP (3mile_score INT);

CREATE TRIGGER update_wscore
AFTER INSERT ON 300 challenge
FOR EACH ROW

INSERT INTO TEMP (3mile_score)
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN TIMEDIFF(3mile, '00:18:00') > '00:00:10'
      THEN CASE 
          WHEN 100 - (EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM TIMEDIFF(3mile, '00:18:00')) * 6 +
               FLOOR(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM TIMEDIFF(3mile, '00:18:00')) / 10)) < 0
            THEN 0
          ELSE 100 - (EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM TIMEDIFF(3mile, '00:18:00')) * 6 +
               FLOOR(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM TIMEDIFF(3mile, '00:18:00')) / 10))
          END
    ELSE 100
    END
FROM 300 challenge
WHERE wscore IS NULL;

UPDATE 300 challenge
SET wscore = pushups * 2 + pullups * 5 + (
    SELECT *
    FROM TEMP
    );

TRUNCATE TABLE TEMP;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have managed to find a workaround for this, if anyone will ever have the patience to read the entire question, if not I will make a short summary of my conclusions here.

Even though I managed to get over the error of not being able to use the same table in a `SELECT` statement and using the value in the `UPDATE` statement like

```
UPDATE table
SET col1 = (select max(col1) from table)
```

by using a temporary table. After managing to create the correct code for that, which is my second CODE posting, in my updated part of the question, I was still unable to make it work as my `WEBHOST` does not allow triggers to be created.

Now, as a workaround for this, I created a new webpage in my application in which, right after `INSERTING` data into the table I instantly updated the columns I needed with the exact code used in the trigger (`INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `TRUNCATE`). I actually moved the functionality of the trigger from the data layer into the business layer of my application.

I hope this helps anyone else who is limited by their webhosts and are not being able to use the full functionality of their data layer.

Answer (score 1):

Try rephrasing this as a `before insert` trigger and modify the values in the `new` record.

The inside of the trigger would be something like this:

```
SET new.wscore = old.pushups * 2 + old.pullups * 5 +
    case 
    WHEN TIMEDIFF (old.3mile , '00:18:00') > '00:00:10' 
      THEN
         CASE 
            WHEN
              100 - (EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM TIMEDIFF (old.3mile, '00:18:00')) * 6 +
              FLOOR(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM TIMEDIFF (old.3mile, '00:18:00')) / 10)) < 0
            THEN 0
         ELSE 
              100 - (EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM TIMEDIFF (old.3mile, '00:18:00')) * 6 +
              FLOOR(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM TIMEDIFF (old.3mile, '00:18:00')) / 10))
         END
  ELSE 100
END;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but I don't think I can get around not having permissions to create TRIGGERS (my webhost doesn't allow it).

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu . . . That does make it harder to implement a trigger.  Instead, wrap your insert logic in a stored procedure and do the work there.  I find it much better to use stored procedures for data modifications anyway, because that provides a better API between the database and an application.

Comment: Maybe you should consider just running your own MySQL. https://www.digitalocean.com/ has dedicated boxes from $5/mo. If you do that as a dedicated MySQL box, you should enable the swap as it initially comes disabled.

Comment: @GordonLinoff And when/how do I call my stored procedures?